# How to request json data from a url and display with ejs in angular js

Tags: node.js, angularjs-directive

I have been trying to get JSON data from an external URL with AngularJS and display in Express EJS templating engine.

This is what what i have tried:

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('http://localhost/drupal3/menu')
    .then(function(response) {
      $scope.links = response.data;
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="row body" ng-app="myApp">

  <!-- content -->
  <div class="col-md-8 content" ng-controller="myController">
    <div class="col-md-12" ng-repeat="link in links">
      <p>{{link.field_add_link}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[This is what i am getting from the browser:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEcMk.jpg)

Comment: have you checked the network tab in developer mode...are you getting some data ?

Comment: what kind of data??
if it is json data ....i am not getting any